# How to write easy php send mail from arrayform html5 template

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

I find nice template in html5 but i need help - how to send email from server to my email address?

```
<div class="title">
    <h2>HTML5 AND CSS3 USE FLAT CONTACT FORM WITH TRANSPARENT EFFECT</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="container" id="my_view">
    <p>Contact</p>
     <div class="stripe"></div>
      <div class="animated">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="top-two">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-one">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Subject"/>
                <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-s">
                <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The designer don't make php file and i don't know how to write to this. Please help me http://www.arrayform.com/2017/02/17/standard-business-contact-form-template/

Comment: You'll need a **server-side** language to generate an email; the form above is only HTML, and that's a client-side language. You'll need to [**try to code your own email script in PHP**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), then update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: have you got good simple php files when i can edit to can send mail from this?
or maybe javascript will be better?? ;)

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'. You're also expected to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and showcase a **specific** problem.

Comment: but this is good question :P I really don't know how to make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a server-side language to generate an email. If you're using PHP, then your code might look like the following:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$to = "sagar@sunitainfosys.com"; 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];          
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

echo $headers = "From:" . "info@sunitainfosys.com";
echo $email_body = "Hi, \n Your Inquiry Information \n My name is $name \n E-mail :- $email \n   Subject :- $subject \n Message :- \n $message ";

if(mail($to,$subject,$email_body,$headers) or mysql_error()) {
?>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    <!-- alert('Your Message Sent Successfully'); -->
    window.location = 'Youpage.php'; 
  </script> 

<?php
}
else {
?>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    <!-- alert('Your Message Not Sent Successfully'); -->
    window.location = 'Youpage.php'; 
  </script> 

<?php
}
?>
```

And now you need to give a `name` to each element in the HTML, like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" />
<textarea placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: thank you for help. i save this like index.php but this is not working :(

Comment: Because you don't post in in `index.php`. You use this code in the file where the form sends its `$_POST`, as defined by the form's `action` attribute (and yours is currently blank at the moment). The above script doesn't contain an `if ($_POST) {}` conditional, so it will error out if run from the same file as the form itself.

Comment: ok it's work thank you! :D
Have you a simple idea hot to dont send Empty form? =)